# Multiple on/off buttons that need to be scalable

Tags: jquery, css, button, toggle

I have been messing around with [some code](http://jsfiddle.net/johniehjelm/zAVqU/4/) (thanks @JohnieHjelm!) I found for toggling buttons. I reduced it to the bare minimum I need and included it in my page. It worked great, for one button. [The problem comes when there's more than one button](http://jsfiddle.net/KwKjd/3/). It starts looking okay, but then it just goes wrong, as you can see in the previous link:

```
<div id = 'settings'>
  <p>
    Links: 
    <span class = 'onoff on'>ON</span>
    <span class = 'onoff'>OFF</span>
    </p><br />
  <p>
    Chapters: 
    <span class = 'onoff on'>ON</span>
    <span class = 'onoff'>OFF</span>
  </p>
</div>

$(function(){
    $('#settings .onoff').click(function(){
        $('#settings .onoff').removeClass("on");
        $(this).addClass("on"); 
    });
});
```

Toggle buttons look okay at first:

[image: Toggle buttons look okay at first]

But when clicked, everything goes wrong:

[image: When clicked, everything goes wrong]

Now, I know I could just call the second button 'onoffb' and repeat the whole $(function()) bit for the new class (or id). It might even work for 2 or 3 buttons, but I wouldn't like at all repeating that bunch of code, even less when there might be 10 or more buttons like this.

I'm not good yet at javascript, and I cannot figure out a way to solve this problem. What should I look into? I need some pointer about where to keep looking for this specific problem. I am thinking about adding an id to each button and, somehow, retrieving it from jquery and modify only that, but I couldn't do it anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folliwing code should do the trick:

```
$(function(){
    $('#settings .onoff').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("on");
        $(this).addClass("on"); 
    });
});
```

The problem was you were selecting all the `.onoff` buttons with the `$("#settings .onoff)` while you only need the siblings (buttons in the same container)

See my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KwKjd/4/

Comment: you can chain the function like this: $(this).addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on");

Answer (score 1):

This might be trivial  and may not answer the question because I'm not sure  what you're asking, but couldn't you just make a  method in javascript  and have a number of buttons parameter.

Kind of like ( psuedocode)

```
function onoff(var Numberofbuttons)
{
Insert code here
}
```

so if you wanted to make x amount of buttons you could use a for loop?

( coming from a C# perspective)

Comment: I thought about doing something like this, but I'm getting to like the way jquery works, taking away the need to throw javascript code in your html with onclick = "onoff('thisid')"

Answer (score 1):

only because you sound like you want to learn and just be pointed instead of given the answer, look into using "this" instead of a specific class.

What that will do is say 'when this is clicked, set this to on/off etc'...

Comment: I see, although user2019515 has given me a good enough answer, do you mean something like this: using the id of `<p>` (which isn't set in my code) or a `<div>`, work with `this` and it's children, so only that `<p>` or `<div>` will get affected?

Comment: Well, 'this' can get confusing in the beginning, but essentially, by using this, that means 'whatever I just clicked on.' So, in your functions that need to affect generic things, like a bunch of off/on buttons, by using 'this' you can add as many buttons/elements etc as you want and not have to go back and modify the actual jquery/javascript.